# Waypoint handlers are continuously triggered when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am attempting to build a site with infinite scroll, comparable to [this site](https://qz.com/1105491/why-it-feels-good-to-be-a-jerk/). Notice that the URL is updated when you scroll down to next article and also when scrolling up to the previous article.

Here is the code that I made. It is executed once when a new article is appended, and creates waypoints for scrolling up and down.

```
function addUrlWaypoint() {
  var $lastArticle = $("article").last();

  $lastArticle.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
      history.pushState(null, "", $lastArticle.data("url"));
    }
  });

  $lastArticle.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction === 'up') {
      history.pushState(null, "", $lastArticle.data("url"));
    }
  }, {
    offset: function() {
      return -$lastArticle.clientHeight
    }
  });
}
```

The code for the offset was taken from [the waypoint docs](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/#function). However, this code triggers continuously when scrolling up and it does so for all articles.

When I change the offset to some value like `-100` it triggers correctly, but I want it to trigger when the bottom comes into the top view (hence the `clientHeight` bit)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer expressed as an example...

```
new Waypoint({
  element: $('#my-element'),
  offset: function () {
    return this.element.height();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer... The example code deals with DOM objects, while I am using a jQuery object.

This leaves the `clientHeight` to be `undefined`, so you should use `height()`